# AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: performance issues when loading multiples beans

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a problem related to performance issuess when using Spring AnnotationConfigApplicationContext. The below image shows what is the structure of my application.

As you can see  I have a menu, when the user clicks a node in the menu, my application reads the name of the form and loads the form(bean) in the working area,. Everything is fine except that the first time when the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext is created and reads the forms package where several hundreds of forms are located, it takes up to 15 seconds to execute that line, of course this is happen once at beginning later clicks last only fractions of a second BUT still 15 seconds is not an acceptable time to wait at the beginning.

So my question is: from an arquitectural point of view, am I using correctly AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ? Does using XML annotation will help performance?

[image]

Comment: Obviously, reducing the number of forms that load would greatly improve performance.  You don't need every one of those forms here, do you?

Comment: Just looked at the docs for AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.  This looks like an object that you stand up one time only, when the application first loads.  Then you would only take your 15 second hit once.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://www.concretepage.com/spring/example_annotationconfigapplicationcontext_spring).  Granted, this is a very small bit of code, but do you notice how an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext is newed up in the main() method?  That's exactly where I would put it.  Create your context object in main(), and then pass it around to whomever needs it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes every one of them is needed because user can click and load any of them in the working area; and of course this object is only created once at the beginning BUT still 15 seconds is not an acceptable time to wait

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the example, I m doing exactly that: creating a class at the begging with a static field (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) that is used across application.

Comment: `15 seconds is not an acceptable time to wait`  -- There are many, many programs that take this long to load, including Office.  Given the amount of work this object is expected to do, you can't expect miracles.

Comment: Just for documentation purposes: I change prototype for request in the scope, but sadly time increase from 15 to 20 - 25 seconds.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see your point when you said 15s is not much time, but your example is a bit misleading in the sense that you are comparing a Desktop app with a Web App. This last just offer the user the possibility to open any of the 300 forms. But I also understand this is the typical behavior of this containe

Comment: AnnotationConfigApplicationContext doesn't seem like a suitable object for your  use case.